# problems occured when solving mazes using DFS

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, maze

I am doing an assignment which creates a maze and then solves it,
I simulate the maze as an array,
using 1 to represent the wall, 0 -- road, 5 -- start, 9 -- destination
if the road has been used, change its value to 2;
it works well for creating mazes,
In most cases, it can find the path to the destination, but sometimes it still pops error stating "empty stack error", like the picture shows...

[[image]]

I can't find the problem(s), may you help me out?

```
package MazeDFS;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

public class maze {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create maze
        //and solve it
        //define the size as 9*9
            int r,c;
            r = 9;
            c = 9;
            int[][] newMaze = mazeGenerator(r,c);
            newMaze[1][1] = 5;
            mazePrinter(newMaze,r,c);
            Stack<Step> path = new Stack<Step>();
            Step s0 = new Step(1,1);
            path.push(s0);
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            newMaze = solve(newMaze, 1, 1, path);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Time length:" + (endTime - startTime));


    }

    public static int[][] mazeGenerator(int x, int y){
        Random randNum = new Random();
        /*I simulated the maze as a x*y array
        Values of the array represent elements of the maze
        0 -- road, 1 -- wall, 5 -- start, 9 -- destination
        */
        int[][] maze = new int[x][y];
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                //bound of the maze
                if(i==0 || j==0 || i==x-1 || j==y-1) {
                    maze[i][j] = 1;
                }
                //build walls
                if(j%2 == 0) {
                    maze[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        //randomly choose a row of every wall and make it a road
        for(int i = 1; i < y-1; i++) {
            int row = randNum.nextInt(x-2)+1;
            maze[row][i] = 0;
        }
        maze[x-2][y-2] = 9;
        return maze;
    }

    public static void mazePrinter(int[][] maze,int x, int y) {
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<y; j++) {
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] solve(int[][] newMaze, int x, int y, Stack<Step> path) {
        mazePrinter(newMaze, 9,9);
        System.out.println();
        if(newMaze[x][y] == 9) {
            Step s = new Step(x,y);
            newMaze[x][y] = 2;
            path.push(s);
            return newMaze;
        }
        //going down
        int dx = 1;
        int dy = 0;
        if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 0 || newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 9) {
            //if visited mark as 2
            if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] != 9) {
                newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] = 2;
            }
            Step ss = new Step(x+dx,y+dy);
            path.push(ss);
            System.out.println("going down");
            return solve(newMaze, x+dx, y+dy, path);
        }
        //going up
        dx = -1;
        dy = 0;
        if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 0 || newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 9) {
            //if visited mark as 2
            if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] != 9) {
                newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] = 2;
            }
            Step ss = new Step(x+dx,y+dy);
            path.push(ss);
            System.out.println("going up");
            return solve(newMaze, x+dx, y+dy, path);
        }
        //turn right
        dx = 0;
        dy = 1;
        if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 0 || newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 9) {
            //if visited mark as 2
            if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] != 9) {
                newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] = 2;
            }
            Step ss = new Step(x+dx,y+dy);
            path.push(ss);
            System.out.println("turn right");
            return solve(newMaze, x+dx, y+dy, path);
        }
        //turn left
        dx = 0;
        dy = -1;
        if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 0 || newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] == 9) {
            //if visited mark as 2
            if(newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] != 9) {
                newMaze[x+dx][y+dy] = 2;
            }
            Step ss = new Step(x+dx,y+dy);
            path.push(ss);
            System.out.println("turn left");
            return solve(newMaze, x+dx, y+dy, path);
        }
        //if their is no way to go then turn back to the last step
        Step sss = path.pop();
        int x1 = sss.getX();
        int y1 = sss.getY();
        System.out.println("return to:"+"x1:"+x +", y1:"+ y);   
        return solve(newMaze, x1, y1, path);
    }
}

class Step{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    Step(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

}
```

Comment: This error appears because you want to pop an element from ``Stack`` but the stack is empty. I guess it's because your maze does not have a path from start to end. 
You have to treat that case, or you should improve your algorithm for designing the maze. Sometimes your generated maze does not have a path

Comment: This can also happen if your maze has loops. You can find yourself in a situation where you're in the middle of the maze and yet all paths have been tried.

Comment: I found the problem, this is because when I search all the way up and then all the way down without finding the road, I need to go back to the crossroads, which has already been poped when the first time I came back, however, I still don't know how to solve it...

Comment: So you say you have a problem with backtracking. A "crossroad" as you call it needs to be popped out only after all its neighbors were visited.